# Edit Tools Options Visibility Problem

Tags: edit-mode

I have gotten into a situation where I cannot seem to get things working correctly. Here is a screen shot of the problem I am having an issue when trying to use tools (like the Extrude tool). I cannot see the options when clicking on the icon for the tool in the edit toolbar.

[image: Extrude Options Problem]

I tried looking this up in the Help document and I thought that when I read was that switching the mode from Global to Local would solve it but it did not. I am trying to learn how to use Blender and this just started happening so now I am kind of stuck. The only way I can access the options for tools that have them is to use the RMD and then select from the pop up menu. I do not understand what has triggered the icon you see with the + sign.

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot shows that the *Extrude Region* tool and gizmo from the toolbar were used. The gizmo is the yellow line with the plus icon that indicates in which direction the extrusion is performed when you click and drag on the icon. You can change the type of extrusion by positioning your mouse cursor on the extrude tool in the toolbar and holding the left mouse button. This will open a menu to select the type of extrusion.

[image: Extrude options]

The properties of the operator can be modified in the *Adjust Last Operation* panel. Use the *Transformation Orientation* to affect the direction of the extrusion. Please note that your options look different in the screenshot because you've executed *Dissolve Selection*.

[image: Properties]

Depending on the type of gizmo additional options may be displayed in the header and sidebar for the active tool. For instance the *Extrude Region* allows you to choose between the *Normal* and *XYZ* option.

[image: Active tool options]

[image: Active tool options]

**Axis Type Normal**

[image: Axis type normal]

**Axis Type XYZ**

[image: Axis type XYZ]

Alternatively you can use the <kbd>E</kbd> key for extruding *without* activating the gizmo.

Comment: Thanks, I got it all sorted out now. Was just a matter of using the E key and also selecting the correct cursor in some situations. Looks like the gizmo is automatically triggered if you just use the mouse button but it can be changed.

Comment: @ntxdave Great. If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.